# Unknown column 'fromip' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

This is my "functions" add-on code I'm using to connect database and this shortcode [plink url=”” name=”” expiry=”” attempts=””] in WP:

```
    $fromip=plad_getip();

$sqla = "select downcode from `permissions` where fromip = '".$fromip."' and url = '{$url}' and timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3600 second) limit 1 ";

$resulta=mysqli_query($conn,$sqla) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resulta)>0){
        return get_option('plad_url').'/download.php?downcode='. plad_mysqli_result($resulta, 0,'downcode');
    }
```

...and Title of my question is my issue.  How do I solve this?

Comment: pretty self-explanatory error. Post your db schema

Answer (score 0):

You don't have fromip field on permissions table.